# How can I get a file name onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to take a file name from onActivityResult

It is startActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

It is onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10){
        Uri uriSound = data.getData();
        // Here I want to get file name String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Uri by following this way

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSound, null, null, null, null);
int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
cursor.moveToFirst();

String fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
```

Comment: Error here `String fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);`

Comment: Maybe `nameIndex` is wrong? It is an audio file.